# CORS Problem using Angular: 8.2.14 and .NET CORE 3.1 REST API Authorization

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, cors

I've been developing a simple Angular project connecting to a REST API developed using .NET CORE 3.1

The problem I'm getting is error on the login using Chrome. I've tried many different options and looked through numerous stackoverflow questions and answers and none have worked. I've tried to add all relevant code and files I could. Please let me know if there is anything else required.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]
This is my web.config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="FORTRESS_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="FORTRESS_APPNAME" value="TEST APP" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="3100" />
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

This is my app.json file code

```
    {
      "AppName": "Contacts Service",
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=FORTDSVM01;Initial Catalog=BankSCL;Integrated Security=true",
      "Kestrel": {
        "EndpointDefaults": {
          "Protocols": "Http1"
        }
      },
      "Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
          "Override": {
            "System": "Warning",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"

          }
        },
        "WriteTo:Async": {
          "Name": "Async",
          "Args": {
            "configure": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "isJson": true,
                  "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact",
                  "path": "c:\\apps\\contacts-svc\\logs\\.log",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                  "fileSizeLimitBytes": "5000000",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": null,
                  "shared": true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "AppSettings": {
          "Secret": "THIS IS USED TO SIGN AND VERIFY JWT TOKENS, REPLACE IT WITH YOUR OWN SECRET, IT CAN BE ANY STRING"
        }
      },
      "Config": {
        "JWTKey": "12345678!@#$%^&*",
        "ValidIssuer": "https://localhost:3100/",
        "ValidAudience": "https://localhost:3100/",
        "SenderMailAddress": "test@gmail.com",
        "SenderMailPassword": "!123ABC!",
        "MailServerName": "smtp.gmail.com",
        "MailPortNumber": "465"
      }
    }

This is my Startup.cs

    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using System.Text;
    using AutoMapper;
    using Fortress.Framework;
    using Fortress.Framework.DependencyInjection;
    using Fortress.Service.Api.Helpers;
    using Fortress.Service.Api.Mapper;
    using Fortress.Service.Api.Repository.Repository;
    using Fortress.Service.Api.Services;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

    namespace Fortress.Service.Api
    {
        public class Startup : ApiBaseStartup<Startup>
        {
            static int Main(string[] args) => Run(args);
           // readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

            protected override void ConfigureApp(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {

               // app.UseHttpsRedirection();

                app.UseRouting();

                app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");

                app.UseAuthorization();
                //app.UseAuthentication();

                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
            }

            protected override void ConfigureAppServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders", build =>
                {
                    build.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                         .AllowAnyMethod()
                         .AllowAnyHeader();
                }));

                services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapperProfile));
                services.AddSqlServer<ContactsContext>(Configuration);
                services.AddSqlServer<PoliciesContext>(Configuration);

                services.AddControllers();

                // configure strongly typed settings objects
                var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
                services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

                //// configure jwt authentication
                var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Config:JWTKey"));

                services.AddAuthentication(x =>
                {
                    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(x =>
                {
                    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    x.SaveToken = true;
                    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        //Same Secret key will be used while creating the token
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        //Usually, this is your application base URL
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Config:ValidIssuer"),
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                        //Here, we are creating and using JWT within the same application.
                        //In this case, base URL is fine.
                        //If the JWT is created using a web service, then this would be the consumer URL.
                        ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Config:ValidAudience"),
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };
                });

                // configure DI for application services
                services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();


            }
        }
    }

This is my launchSettings.json

{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3100", //64929
      "sslPort": 3100
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchUrl": "api/ping",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "FORTRESS_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Fortress.Service.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "FORTRESS_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:3100;http://localhost:3000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/api/ping",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "FORTRESS_URLS": "https://+:3100;http://+:80",
        "FORTRESS_HTTPS_PORT": "3100"
      },
      "httpPort": 3000,
      "useSSL": true,
      "sslPort": 3100
    }
  }
}
```

This is my User Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Fortress.Framework;
using Fortress.Service.Api.Business.Contacts;
using Fortress.Service.Api.Models;
using Fortress.Service.Api.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
//using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace Fortress.Service.Api.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [FortressApi("Users")]
      public class UsersController : FortressController
    {
        private IUserService _userService;

        public UsersController(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        // [AllowAnonymous]
        //[EnableCors("AllowAllHeaders")]
        [HttpPost("ValidateCredentials")]
        [Route("Login")]
        public async Task<UserCredentialOutput> ValidateCredentials(
            [FromServices] IGetCredentialService service,
            [FromBody] UserCredentialInput userCredentialInput, CancellationToken token)
        {

            var response = await ExecuteServiceAsync(service, userCredentialInput, token);
            response.Password = userCredentialInput.Password;

            var user = _userService.Authenticate(response);
            return new UserCredentialOutput
            {
                ContactID = user.ContactID,
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName,
                UserName = user.UserName,
                Roles = user.Roles,
                EmailID = user.EmailID,
                Token = user.Token
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Angular service function calling the API

```
validateCredentials(formData: FormData): Observable<UserCredentialOutput> {


        return this.api.post<UserCredentialOutput>('Users/Login', formData);


    }
```

I completely forgot to add my Startup.cs file -- here it is

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using AutoMapper;
using Fortress.Framework;
using Fortress.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Fortress.Service.Api.Helpers;
using Fortress.Service.Api.Mapper;
using Fortress.Service.Api.Repository.Repository;
using Fortress.Service.Api.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors;

namespace Fortress.Service.Api
{
    public class Startup : ApiBaseStartup<Startup>
    {
        static int Main(string[] args) => Run(args);
       // readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        protected override void ConfigureApp(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {


            //app.UseOptions();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");
            //app.UseMvc();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }

        protected override void ConfigureAppServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders", build =>
            {
                build.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                     .AllowAnyMethod()
                     .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

            services.AddMvc();

            //services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            //{
            //    options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowMyOrigin"));
            //});

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapperProfile));
            services.AddSqlServer<ContactsContext>(Configuration);
            services.AddSqlServer<PoliciesContext>(Configuration);

            services.AddControllers();

            // configure strongly typed settings objects
            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            //// configure jwt authentication
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Config:JWTKey"));

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    //Same Secret key will be used while creating the token
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    //Usually, this is your application base URL
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Config:ValidIssuer"),
                ValidateAudience = true,
                    //Here, we are creating and using JWT within the same application.
                    //In this case, base URL is fine.
                    //If the JWT is created using a web service, then this would be the consumer URL.
                    ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Config:ValidAudience"),
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });

            // configure DI for application services
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just role back all the changes you made to the web.config and add the following code to the Configure method in your Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
```

Comment: web api require to set cors via code, not web.config

Comment: I forgot to add my Startup.cs file. It's above now. I've taken the  <httpProtocol> and customHeaders> out of the web.config file. Same problem. It works in postman fine. Just when I push from my angular project it errors out every time.

Comment: It is working with postman because postman does not set the origin header, but browsers do set this header in the request. It's not angular's problem. You just need to fix it in your .net core code and it will work fine.

Comment: Remove the services.AddCors... block from the ConfigureAppServices method in startup.cs and change the app.UseCors method in ConfigureApp method in the same file to the format provided in this answer

Comment: Ok, I've removed the following from the ConfigureAppServices
 // services.AddCors();
    
and added the following to the ConfigureApp
app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
            });

No Joy. :(

Comment: Is your code running on windows or linux? What is your web server? Is there a reverse proxy or something in the middle of the way to the API?

Comment: It's running on windows server 2012. I'm running it from code. Visual studio 2019 for API and visual studio code for angular front end.

Comment: I've finally figured it out. The startup.cs had an inherited class that was overwriting the configuration of the CORS. It took some deep digging but I finally figured it out. Thanks all.